# Wrap text in a line vector layer QGIS 3.24

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I need to wrap labels of a line vector layer.
Is there a way to do this in QGIS 3.24 ?[image]

I want my labels look like this:

[image]

Comment: Using placement mode curved, it seems not to be possible. Using parallel mode, it works, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Parallel mode means that i should draw another parallel line and type in attribute a part of text which i want to be wrapped? (NAPLES)

Comment: No - in the label settings, go to `Placement` tab and change the mode from curved to parallel. It doesn't look nice as in your screensot, though.

Answer (score 2):

As Babel pointed out this is possible in a roundabout way by wrapping the text and then amending the placement in the layer styling properties. Appreciate you may need more flexibility than this so it might be worth submitting a feature request unless there is already one.

**GIF**

[image]

Comment: Its not what i want but this can be a solution for some cases.